# Baking point light URP

Tags: unity-game-engine, light, urp

I use URP for my Unity 3d project. I have many point lights in my scene, they all set to mixed and important light. However some point lights does not produce any light on the scene after the baking.

Before baking:
[image]

After baking:
[image]

If I mark them as baked light instead of mixed than they just go completely black.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In URP there is a [limit](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@11.0/manual/universalrp-builtin-feature-comparison.html) for realtime point lights. You can´t set more than 8 point lights. This is the reason, that in "mixed mode" some of your point lights are producing lights and the others don´t. Nevertheless baked lighting should produce a result for every point light. Probably the light setup is not correct. Try to follow some basic URP lighting tutorials [i.e. on youtube](https://youtu.be/okYhs6kQ0xw)